# syntax to compile 16 bit (8086code) in nasm

Tags: nasm, emu8086

**I'm confused how to compile 8086 code in nasm.

i used following command to assemble:**

- **nasm hello.asm -o hello.o**   //;(Something wrong with this?)

**This is 8086 Hello world code:**

```
USE16
.model small

.stack 100h
.data
msg db "Hello World !$"
.code
main proc near

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov dx, offset msg
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov ah,00
    int 21h

endp
end main
```

**And this is the output**

nasm hello.asm -o hello.o
hello.asm:3: error: parser: instruction expected
hello.asm:4: error: parser: instruction expected
hello.asm:5: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
hello.asm:9: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
hello.asm:11: error: parser: instruction expected
hello.asm:16: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
hello.asm:23: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
hello.asm:24: error: parser: instruction expected

Comment: This code looks like it was written for MASM not NASM.  They have differences in syntax, directives, etc.  You'll need to do some work to convert the code.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Thank You!